# Почему при вводе любого числа от 0 до 3 выводится explorer?

Tags: c++, c, char, switch, scanf

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void GetProg(TCHAR szCMDline[]) 
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = TRUE;
    BOOL bExitSt = CreateProcess (NULL, szCMDline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    if(bExitSt)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle (pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle (pi.hProcess);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char imp=0;
    printf("\tPrint number for programm open.\n");
    printf(" 1 -- open explorer \n 2 -- open world (windows) \n 3 -- open notepad (windows) \n 0 -- exit programm\n\n");
    printf(">>>> ");
    imp = scanf("%c",&imp);
switch(imp){
    case 1:{
        GetProg(TEXT("explorer"));
        break;
    }
    case 2:{
        GetProg(TEXT("write"));
        break;
    }
    case 3:{
        GetProg(TEXT("notepad"));
        break;
    }
    case 0:{
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` возвращает значение, равное числу успешно считанных и записанных в переданные параметры значений. Таким образом она всегда возвращает 1 и перезаписывает введённое значение.  Вместо `imp = scanf("%c",&imp);` пишите `scanf("%c",&imp);`

Comment: Либо `char imp=0; scanf("%c",&imp); ... case '1'`, либо `char imp=0; scanf("%c",&imp); imp -= '0'; ... case 1`, либо `int imp=0; scanf("%d",&imp); ... case 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) возвращает количество успешно назначенных аргументов или [`EOF`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Вы присваиваете этот результат переменной `imp`, и в случае успеха она всегда будет содержать значение `1`. Не нужно делать это присваивание:

```cpp
scanf("%c",&imp);
```

Также вам нужно поменять константные выражения в операторе `switch` на символы:

```cpp
switch(imp){
    case '1':{
        GetProg(TEXT("explorer"));
        break;
    }
    case '2':{
        GetProg(TEXT("write"));
        break;
    }
    case '3':{
        GetProg(TEXT("notepad"));
        break;
    }
    case '0':{
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
}
```